# How secure is a live bamboo fence compare to chain link or barbed wire fences?

Tags: fence, security

We're about to start working on securing our house. One thing we know we need on the back part of our property is a fence of some sort. I'm trying to keep costs down but security up. I know that any fence I choose will only delay an intruder from leaving or arriving. I have access to unlimited bamboo from a neighboring farm, so my only cost in a live bamboo fence would be labor in planting it. So, I'd like to know if a live bamboo fence would provide similar security features as other fence styles like barbed wire or chain link.

I already know about the spreading potential of bamboo and it doesn't concern me for the space where I would be planting it.

Comment: you should check local invasive species lists and make sure the type of bamboo you plant is not on it. Bamboo can be a very aggressive plant and some varieties are considered invasive.

Comment: I live in Honduras in a very rural area. No such lists exist here. :)

Comment: I'd put the bamboo in. Plant them as close together as you can. Give it a high nitrogen bath or teach an animal to use the area as the go to place and once new shoots start coming up, slowly weave them together as best as you can and within 2 yrs you'll have a very thick deterrent. After awhile you can start harvesting and then build a fence in front/back of it out of it for additional security.

Answer (score 3):

I came across some of these in New Zealand.  About 2 feet thick, and bloody well impenetrable. Also completely unclimbable.  You're not stopping a chainsaw, arsonist or bulldozer, but neither is a wood fence.

Comment: How tightly together is the bamboo spaced? I lived at a house with bamboo and while it was tough to get through, it wasn't impenetrable. In fact, I regularly went in there to retrieve dog toys and stuff. It is an excellent privacy screen, though.

Comment: This was pretty tight -- Kind of like a Escher painting, where the space between bamboo stalks is another bamboo stalk.